# Google App Engine - Update JPA 1 to JPA 2

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, jpa-2.0, datanucleus

I want to update my GAE web app to use JPA 2.0. From the doc [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jpa/overview-dn2#Setting_Up_JPA_2_0), it says that I have to copy the content of `appengine-java-sdk/lib/opt/user/datanucleus/v2/` to `lib` folder of the project.

This are the files of `appengine-java-sdk/lib/opt/user/datanucleus/v2/`:

1. asm-4.0.jar
2. datanucleus-api-jdo-3.1.3.jar
3. datanucleus-api-jpa-3.1.3.jar
4. datanucleus-appengine-2.1.2.jar
5. datanucleus-core-3.1.3.jar
6. geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec-1.0.jar
7. jdo-api-3.0.1.jar
8. jta-1.1.jar

Currently, this are the content of project's `lib` folder that might affect the migration:

1. appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.7.1.jar
2. appengine-api-labs.jar
3. appengine-endpoints.jar
4. appengine-jsr107cache-1.7.7.1.jar
5. asm-3.3.jar
6. asm-commons-3.3.jar
7. asm-tree-3.3.jar
8. datanucleus-appengine-1.0.10.final.jar
9. datanucleus-core-1.1.5.jar
10. datanucleus-jpa-1.1.5.jar
11. geronimo-jpa_3.0_spec-1.1.1.jar
12. geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar
13. jdo2-api-2.3-eb.jar
14. jsr107cache-1.1.jar

Which files should I delete? I tried to delete files which have new version but eclipse is looking for older files:

1. datanucleus-appengine-1.0.10.final.jar
2. datanucleus-core-1.1.5.jar
3. geronimo-jpa_3.0_spec-1.1.1.jar

This is my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="transactions-optional">
        <provider>org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jpa.DatastorePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalRead" value="true"/>
            <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalWrite" value="true"/>
            <property name="datanucleus.ConnectionURL" value="appengine"/>

            <property name="datanucleus.appengine.ignorableMetaDataBehavior" value="NONE"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Any help on this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using Datanucleus requires eclipse plugin check this [link](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/jdo/guides/eclipse.html)

Change Persistence Provider to in your `persistence.xml` `org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl` JPA 2.0 Provider more [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jpa/overview-dn2)

Change every single library with the same new one

here is a screen shot of my application
Note* Using GAE 1.7.4

[image: GAE-lib here]

Comment: I deleted the old files but my eclipse said missing those files, how to fix it?

Comment: Try Cleaning the project : Project >> Clean

Comment: I already cleaned the project. The solution is `Right Click Project >> Properties >> Google >> App Engine >> Datastore >> Datanucleus version = v2`

Comment: Yes, Sorry I've forgotten to tell you about it :)